# Angular reactive form validate required status in child control

Tags: angular, angular-validation, controlvalueaccessor, angular12

I've got a custom component that implements `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator`. The component is used in a `form` and I set the `formControlName` on the custom control when it's created in the HTML.

All of that is working great, but the piece missing is having the child's `input` control know that it's supposed to be required. I'm using bootstrap to have fields show red when there's no value in a required component, but this child component doesn't trigger that error.

What do I need to return, from the `validate` method, to signal the error? I have the below as the start of my validation, and it does see the field is required, and that it doesn't have a value, but I'm not sure what the return should be on failure.

```js
validate(c: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (c.value)
        return c.value instanceof WorkerDTO ? null : {isWorkerObject: false}

    const validator = c.validator?.({} as AbstractControl)
    return validator && validator.required ? {hasValue: false} : null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can return something like this

```js
validate(c: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const validator = c.validator?.({} as AbstractControl)
    if (validator && validator.required) {
        if (c.value === undefined || c.value === null) 
            return {c: true}
```

from the angular documentation

> The validation error object typically has a property whose name is the validation key, .... , and whose value is an arbitrary dictionary of values that you could insert into an error message,

edit.

my answer show to return a field as invalid. then if you want to show the explicit error in the view, one way is to grab the error in the html with the name of the validator

eg from [angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation):

```html
<div *ngIf="name.errors?.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.forbiddenName">//this is a custom validator
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>
```

Comment: That says the control is invalid, yes, but it doesn't explicitly say that the required value is missing, and thus the CSS from bootstrap doesn't color the control in red.

Comment: you have to do more validator for your purpose. an example, 1 validator for the length, 1 validator for the regex patter. then you have to grab in the html with the name of the validator like `<div *ngIf="name.errors?.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.regexPattern">
    Name must have only valid character
  </div>`